# Remove varying substring (semester name) from given string

Tags: c#

I have a database of courses that are formatted with the course title and semester.

Some examples:

- ARCH 6359 Spring 2015
- BIOL 3324 Fall 2013
- ENGI 2304 SP15
- GCSW FA 13
- GENB 4350 Summer 2011
- GROUP Writing Consultations 2011Fall
- YES Prep Fa12

(fa-fall sp-spring)

I need make a copy and remove the semester from each of these strings. The inconsistencies in format are causing me a huge headache.

Any input on how to start this task would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow... that formatting is... bad. I see where the headaches are coming from. But most likely someone is going to suggest regex here. I'm not gifted enough to think of a solution offhand.

Comment: Also, where is your DB getting this information. Correct this at the source as much as possible (if at all). The 'ol "garbage in, garbage out" comes to play a little here.

Comment: @DangerZone I have a local database with around 2000 rows of student info. REALLY don't want to manually fix that lol. My plan is to add another column to the table with just the course title. I am an undergraduate student and got hired as a web app dev at my college so I am still learning a lot.

Comment: I understand why you wouldn't want to do that. Although, if you do come up with a solution and manage to standardize these programmatically, I'd rewrite all fixed values back to the DB so this doesn't crop up again. Shouldn't take too long once this is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a whack at it.  The hard part (and first thing to do before manipulating the data) is to split your string into tokens that actually make sense.

So split each string by spaces and where letters/digits meet, do some string cleanup, and remove all unwanted tokens.  Seems to work for your inputted data.

```
private static void Main()
{
     var list = new[]
     {
         "ARCH 6359 Spring 2015", "BIOL 3324 Fall 2013", "ENGI 2304 SP15", "GCSW FA 13", "GENB 4350 Summer 2011",
         "GROUP Writing Consultations 2011Fall", "YES Prep Fa12"
     };

     var toRemove = new[] {"SP", "SPRING", "FA", "Fall", "Summer"};

     foreach (var str in list)
     {
        var items = Regex.Split(str, @"(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(\s+)")
                .Select(i => i.Trim())
                .Where(i => i != "" && !toRemove.Contains(i, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ",items));
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Produces:

```
ARCH 6359 2015
BIOL 3324 2013
ENGI 2304 15
GCSW 13
GENB 4350 2011
GROUP Writing Consultations 2011
YES Prep 12
```

Comment: Depending what OP defines as "semester" (season AND year, or just season) you might also have to split out the year...

Comment: Crap, he probably does mean the year as well.  Kinda makes this code useless

Comment: Splitting out year is almost downright impossible if a course code could be the same value as a year. If not, then there's something much more doable. Still doesn't seem safe to me.

Comment: yeah I do need the dates removed too. I haven't used Regex yet, so I think I'm going to check out some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Because i also do not see any real pattern to apply to all the strings. I would create function that take care of the different sub groups that can occur.

From what I am seeing I make out 5 different patterns:

Spring 2015 (SemesterNameFull + " "+ Year)

SP 15 (SemesterNameShort + " " + ShortYear)

FA12 (SemesterNameShort+ShortYear)

Summer 2011 (SemesterNameFull+ " " + Year)

2011Fall (Year + SemesterNameFull)

You could use code to create all instances for a time period and then use a simple select & replace to get rid of most of them.

Comment: Assuming the same pattern/combo of short/long year, space/no space, short/long semester holds and we don't actually have examples for everything in his DB, we would have to account for all 16 possible combinations.. (unless we hear otherwise that it is limited to these 5 patterns only)

Comment: I meant that I just saw 5 patterns. The total number of combinations could be in the hundreds.  e.g. you could have SP 00, SP 01, SP 02, SP 03, SP 04, SP 05, SP 06, SP 07 and so on.